# How to handle variable scope elegantly in Python?

Tags: python, scope, global

I thought that I could update a variable declared at the top of a Python script from within a function, but that's not true. I manage to do that using `global`:

```
count = 0

def updateCount():
    global count
    print count
    count = (count+1)%10

for x in xrange(10):
    updateCount()
```

Is this the best way to handle this ( a function updating a variable at a higher level) ?
What is the 'pythonic' way of dealing with this. global seems a bit loose.

Also, please let me know if this is already answered and I'll close the question. I've been reading quite a few answers already posted close to the issue, but not quite there.

Comment: Use the return value of functions: e.g. `count = updateCount(count)`. For state that must be preserved (and perhaps mutated), consider objects to store such data.

Comment: Simply don't use a global variable. The language is deliberately designed to make it hard for you to reassign names in the global namespace in a function, so why fight it? Either reassign the global variable explicitly in the global scope, by writing `updateCount` to have a parameter and assigning `count = updateCount(count)`, or use a mutable object with methods to change its own state (increment a `count` attribute in your case).

Comment: The most pythonic way is not use globals.

Comment: @user2246674 return value is the simplest solution so far, will use classes later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple solutions exists, depending on what you want to achieve.

Some was already mentioned in the comments to your question:

- Create a class. `updateCount` is a method, `count` is an attribute
- Return value from `updateCount` instead of using global `count`

Also you can use

- Closures
- Generators

IMHO, the most "pytohnic" (read "cool") way could be to use generators, here's an example

```
def updateCount(x):
    count = 0
    for i in xrange(x):
        count = (count+1) % 10
        yield count

for i in updateCount(15):
    print i
```

Comment: that's pretty cool. Am going to use user2246674's return value suggestion for now and later refactor and use a class